# How do I set a custom validation error on a specific form field in Play! 2.*

Tags: validation, playframework-2.0

Basically I have a following form class.

```
public static class BasicForm {
    @Required
    public String name;
    @Required
    @Email
    public String email;
    @Required
    public String password;
    @Required
    public String confirmPassword;

    public List<ValidationError> validate() {
        if (User.findByEmail(email) != null) {
            List<ValidationError> validationErrorList = new ArrayList<ValidationError>();
            validationErrorList.add(new ValidationError("email", "error.alreadyexists", new ArrayList<Object>()));
            return validationErrorList;
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

As you can see, I am trying to validate the uniqueness of the email address.
If email is not unique, **I would like to display the error message on the email field, NOT as a global error message**

What is the correct way of implementing validate() method to achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use a `validate` method with the following signature:

```java
public Map<String, List<ValidationError>> validate()
```

This way you can add errors to single fields like this:

```java
Map<String, List<ValidationError>> errors = null;
if (emailIsBad) {
    errors = new HashMap<String, List<ValidationError>>();
    List<ValidationError> list = new ArrayList<ValidationError>();
    list.add(new ValidationError("email", "email is bad"));
    errors.put("email", list);
}
return errors;
```

please note that if you should return an *empty* map, it still will render the form as erroneous. If you want the `validate()` method to succeed, you need to return null.

Comment: how did you guys get this to work? List<> cannot be instantiated since it's an interface. Also, String does not implicitly convert to ValidationError, so list.add("email is bad") also does not work. I am not very experienced with Java or Play so, maybe it's something that I've missed?

Comment: @LeoHernandez I updated the sample code a bit to address your questions.

Comment: really helps me !! 100K thanks ! I now use this to avoid having global errors who were actually concerning specific field, Great!

Answer (score 1):

Not enough rep to comment (yet), but don't forget to include the proper import statement:

```
import.play.data.validation.*;
```

I wasted a few minutes due to an incorrect statement.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with based on Daniel's 
code:
My code checks for password confirmation, tho.

```
public Map<String, List<ValidationError>> validate() {
       Map<String, List<ValidationError>> errors = null;

            if (!password.equals(confirmPassword)) {
                errors = new HashMap<>();
                List<ValidationError> list = new ArrayList<>();
                list.add(new ValidationError("password", "Passwords do not match"));
                errors.put("password",list);
                errors.put("confirmPassword", list);
            }

            return errors;
        }
```